# Convert a string into the Datefromat and compare it with current date

Tags: date, swift3

Hi I want to convert a string "2017-02-05T00:00:00+05:30" to the IST date in same format as it is. and the want to compare it with current date(NSDate())
    But when i convert it using below code i get a day less . i used different time format but not able to find the exact timefromat for "2017-02-05T00:00:00+05:30"

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.local
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: LAST_ATTENDANCE!)

 let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: LAST_ATTENDANCE!)! as NSDate
 let endDate:NSDate =  NSDate()
```

and this code give me a nil

```
 let mydate = "2017-02-05T00:00:00+05:30"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: mydate)
 print("mydate: \(mydate), date: \(date)")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `TimeZone.current` is DateFormatter's default

Comment: setting the dateFormat two times and changing timezone between them makes no sense

Comment: Just get the date from your string and just use DateFormatter again to display it with whatever timezone you want and you can use any format when displaying it.

Comment: BTW there is no milliseconds in your date string

Comment: try like this `let mydate = "2017-02-05T00:00:00+05:30"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "enUS_POSIX")
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: mydate) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}`

Comment: Its working fine Thanks a lot @LeoDabus